# Bash, [.bashrc] a function for an alias

Tags: bash, scripting

[In my .bashrc]

Basically I try to make an alias:

```
alias e='su -c'
```

But when I write in a terminal:

```
~$ e ls -goFha /root
```

I (obviously) get the error:

```
su: group oFha does not exist
```

---

If $str were replaced by the rest of the command, the herebelow code would work:

```
alias e='su -c "$str"'
```

But alias don't work this way. Therefore, I thought to a function.

Replacing $str by the whole argument string, it could be something like:

```
e () {
  "su -c '$str'"
}
```

How to get the whole argument string in a function?

How would you write my function?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just `e "ls -goFha /root"`? Or are you trying to avoid the quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another solution:

```
e() { 
   su -c "$*"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
    e () {
      CMD="$@"
      su -c "$CMD"
    }
```

Comment: try this: "su -c /usr/bin/$@"

Comment: bash: su -c /usr/bin/ls: No such file or directory

Comment: { su -c "$@" } >> "su: group oFh does not exist"

Comment: I'm looking for a way to avoid using quotes. Else, an <alias e="su -c"> is enought.

Comment: We got it. Thanks, it's also what I found. Thanks